# Why's my getTimeZone().getDisplayName reporting wrong offset?

Tags: java, android, calendar, timezone, timezone-offset

I am testing my app in different timezones. I manually changed my physical phone's timezone to be London UK which is GMT+00:00

However, when I print the timezone using `myCalendar.getTimeZone().getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT)`, it prints:

`GMT+01:00`

Why's it adding an hour to the offset?

**EDIT:**

By setting the `getDisplayName`'s first parameter to false, I get the correct `GMT+00:00` but I am not sure why I should be setting it to false. As far as I know, London UK is always `GMT+00:00`? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I know, London UK is always GMT+00:00? Am I wrong?

Yes, you are wrong.  The United Kingdom observes Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) in the winter, and observes daylight saving time, locally called "British Summer Time" (BST), in the summer.

- GMT = UTC+00:00
- BST = UTC+01:00

Reference [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london), and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_Kingdom).

Comment: > United Kingdom observes Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) in the winter

If that's the case and currently it's winter time, then why's it reporting GMT+01:00? Shouldn't it report 0 right now and 1 in summer?

Comment: No. The first parameter controls that, not the time you run the code. You specified `true`, so you get the one that applies during daylight saving time - regardless of if it's daylight saving time right now or not.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense then! Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

According to the API, getDisplayName()'s first parameter indicates if daylight savings should be used.

> Returns a name in the specified style of this TimeZone suitable for
>   presentation to the user in the default locale. If the specified
>   daylight is true, a Daylight Saving Time name is returned (even if
>   this TimeZone doesn't observe Daylight Saving Time). Otherwise, a
>   Standard Time name is returned.

This is probably why the time is an hour ahead with that value set to true, as a value of true will cause a daylight savings hour even if it isn't observed in that timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the quote, it’s to the point. As the other answer explains, summer time (DST) *is* used in London (then it remains to be seen what they choose after Brexit). You can’t just add one hour regardless of the time zone since (1) the correction could be 30 minutes or 2 hours (2) in case of time zone abbreviation like `IST` for example, you cannot invent a summer time aware abbreviation that doesn’t exist.